# How to catch mouse event and keyboard event

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I have developed a web browser i want to catch both keyboard events and mouse events.if mouse events and keyboard events not happen in a given  period  how to catch it.

Comment: what did you just say? you have developed a web browser?

Comment: Please rephrase your question... it doesn't make sense

Comment: I believe you have used web browser control on winform application. and you want to capture events on that control. please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET

this might help you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events and keyboard events can be catched in dotnet by using windows hooks.These hooks are created with a p/invoke call to [SetWindowsHookEx](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804).

In particular, there are only two type of hooks that you can use: 
the low-level keyboard and mouse hooks, known as WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL, these are what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                //make some action
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

this is how to catch the Escape key in the keyboard.
and check this for more about mouse events 
[Mouse Events](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_20661377.html)